# Как записывать скринвидео со звуком через ffmpeg?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, запись, звукозапись

Хочу в Windows записывать рабочий стол со звуком звук (одновременно и воспроизводимые звуки, и звуки с микрофона).

Обязательное требование - все используемые программы должны быть бесплатны (в том числе для коммерческого использования) и не требовать админских прав (в том числе для установки).

Вроде бы подходит `ffmpeg`. Как им записывать экран я нашёл:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -vcodec h264 -f avi some.avi
```

Но вот со звуком гуглится только про linux, а мне надо windows.

Comment: https://obsproject.com/ - эту штуку не пробовал? Я на неё ссылку кидал ещё в том старом вопросе.

Comment: @donRumata, настраивать его надо. По умолчанию масштабируется до 1280*720, 4 минуты занимают 80 МБ, причём качество так себе (не знаю, из-за масштабирования или нет). И ещё x64-версия не работает.

Comment: @donRumata, поменял разрешение -вроде нормально записывает. Но вот размер файлов мне не очень нравится... И flv-формат - тоже.